# Can't get value from model and place in output C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've started building a MVC application using C#, but when I tried to get `model` value from the `view` (`Index.cshtml`) it outputed the error "value cannot be null" in the view file. I tried `.ToString()` and `new HtmlString` on the string from the model, but nothing worked. how can I solve this?

View - Razor - in VS debugging, showing the property has assignment in the page object, and also showing the error.
[image: Screenshot from VS debugging]

Model Assignment in the controller:

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            PageProps props = new PageProps();
            props.userNameOut = Session["User"].ToString();
            return View(props);
        }
```

Comment: It's the second argument to `Path.Combine` that is null. Namely, `Model.properties["logoImageName"]`

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the `return View(props)` line to see if it actually get there?

Comment: Thanks @haim770, fixed by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio show error message at line 19 but the real error may be at **lines** after.
Please check null for `Model.properties` and all properties from `Model` below.

Change from

`Model.properties["logoImageName"]`

to

`Model.properties != null && Model.properties.ContainsKey("logoImageName") ? Model.properties["logoImageName"] : string.Empty`